# Data usage: wudfhost.exe sending a lot of data to a local IP adrress

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8

I installed [GlassWire](https://www.glasswire.com/) the other day to monitor excess web traffic. I noticed though that the Windows service "c:\windows\system32\wudfhost.exe" which is the "Windows Driver Foundation - User-mode Driver Framework Host Process" is sending a lot of data (about 2.4GB just today) to what seems to be a local IP `192.168.173.207` although my local ip is `192.168.0.3`.

I have tried pinging that address, but I get a time out error. I'm just wondering if anyone knows what this might be.

[image: http://postimg.org/image/dp4k0y91p/]

Comment: use Processhacker to see which device uses the wudfhost.exe: http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/172209-how-do-i-determine-what-wudfhostexe-is-doing-and-what-its-associ/?p=1084210

Comment: Thanks @magicandre1981 I found what it was. Will add the answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the culprit when my girlfriend suggested "is it that wireless thing you just bought?" I had recently purchased a [Microsoft Wireless Display Adapter](http://www.cnet.com/au/products/microsoft-wireless-display-adapter/), which apparently uses [Wi-Fi Direct](http://www.wi-fi.org/discover-wi-fi/wi-fi-direct) to create a local independent wireless network.

The gigabytes of data that were being sent through `wudfhost.exe` was the video data being sent wirelessly to my TV HDMI. So simple.

When connected to the TV I can also ping the address, and browse to a "dongle configuration" page too.